# posting form data into a form on another website

Tags: php, ajax, jsonp

Im trying to post data from this form into:
http://www.vebra.com/mdhtest/property/search/2
does anyone have any suggestions? ive looked into cors but it doesnt seem like its available to be used on the server on that site
 `enter code here`
    
        Property Search
        
            Number Of Bedrooms
                
                Studio
                No preference
                1+
                2+
                3+
            
        
        
            
                Minimum Price
                
                    £0 p.w.
                    £50 p.w.
                    £100 p.w.
                    £150 p.w.
                    £200 p.w.

Im trying to post data from this form into:
http://www.vebra.com/mdhtest/property/search/2

does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What does "post data from this form" or "posting form data into a form" mean? Are you trying to make the user's browser go to someone else's website and then change the content of that website?

Comment: You have to know how the script at the receiving end is going to handle the data the form is sending. Your best bet is to contact the developers managing it at the other end and check - it would be polite to ask them if they object to you doing this as well.